# MongoEngine cannot connect through Atlas Uri string. Tried everything

Tags: python, mongodb, ssl, kivy, mongoengine

I'm new to programming and am building my first app.. I'm building a kivy app trying to use mongoDB as the database. I can connect to a localhost to query and create documents. I cannot get it to connect to the atlas no matter what I try. I'm also using Pycharm and a venv.

Heres the basic info:

```py
import pymongo
from pymongo.server_api import ServerApi
import mongoengine as mongo
import ssl

data = 'events'
username = 'admin'
password = 'abc123'
host_name = 'mongodb+srv://events.xfmhxnj.mongodb.net'
uri = f'mongodb+srv://{username}:{password}@events.xfmhxnj.mongodb.net/'

mongo.connect(db=db,
              username=username,
              password=password,
              host=host_name)


class Obj(mongo.Document):
    name = mongo.StringField(required=True)


div = Obj()
div.name = 'test'
div.save()
```

which gives me this error: `raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError( pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: ac-liums0m-shard-00-00.xfmhxnj.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Then i looked up this error and found someone recommended:

```py
mongo.connect(db=db,
              username=username,
              password=password,
              host=host_name,
              ssl=True,
              ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE,)
)
```

error: `raise ConnectionFailure(f"Cannot connect to database {alias} :\n{e}") mongoengine.connection.ConnectionFailure: Cannot connect to database default : Unknown option ssl_cert_reqs`

I don't understand why its an unknown option. pymongo has it listed in the example.
https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.3.0/examples/tls.html

I've also tried the string straight from Atlas:

```py
client = pymongo.MongoClient(f"mongodb+srv://{username}:{password}@events.xfmhxnj.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority", server_api=ServerApi('1'))
db = client.test
client.server_info()
```

error: `raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError( pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: ac-liums0m-shard-00-01.xfmhxnj.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate`

or if i just paste in the uri string from compass

```
mongo.connect('mongodb+srv://admin:abc123@events.xfmhxnj.mongodb.net/test')
```

error: `raise InvalidName("database names cannot contain the character %r" % invalid_char) pymongo.errors.InvalidName: database names cannot contain the character '.'`

any help is super appreciated! I feel like i've tried every combination of connection settings. This is the last thing i need before pushing my app to x-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `MongoClient(connection_string, tlsCAFile=certifi.where())` ?

> Certifi provides Mozilla’s carefully curated collection of Root
> Certificates for validating the trustworthiness of SSL certificates
> while verifying the identity of TLS hosts.

Before testing the new code remember to do "`pip install certifi`".